# Meanings of Reichaft?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

I was reviewing a photo taken sometime around the late 1800's, trying to figure out where it may have been taken.  It's of a copper / ironware / tinware store.  There's some German on the sign, saying "Blechwaaren Reichaft", or something very close.  The Blechwaaren appears to mean something about blackware / sheet metal, but I haven't been able to decipher Reichaft.  Is it a trade name?  DeepL suggests kingdom, SYSTRAN suggests righteousness or riches, is there a better meaning in this context?

Relevant part of image:
[image: Crop of relevant part of image]

Comment: Ah.  That makes sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @CarstenS Should I edit to change, or do you want to write an answer, or...?

Comment: I had not answered because I was not sure whether the question is on-topic. All good now.

Comment: Can somebody explain why it says *Blechwaaren* and not *Blechwaren*? Maybe Low German?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid you *misread* a „G“ for an „R“.<sup>1</sup>  The 3rd letter is an “s”, not an “i” (and also not an “f”, the more common misunderstanding).
Combined with the very faded diacritics (it’s „ä“, not „a“), the word is simply:

> **Geschäft**

I.e. **store** or **shop.**

---

<sup>1</sup>  A very common confusion when reading Fraktur with a Latin script background. The German Wikipedia has a list of “false friends” and a handy conversion table [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur_(Schrift)#Schreib-_und_Lesehilfe).